# How to add glassfish server on a remote windows server to netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I have been trying to add my glassfish server installation on a windows server that is on my network to netbeans on my laptop but no luck.

The Glassfish server is already installed on the server and it works properly. but I cant seems to add it to my netbeans on my laptop to get it to work.

Netbeans detects that it is a valid installation but I cant start the glassfish server from netbeans.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: any error msg from netbeans?? What happens when you start glassfish server..?

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable remote login from external servers by using the command asadmin enable-secure-admin